# Showing that an oscillator has its amplitude reduced after completing half-cycle

Tags: problem-solving, classical-mechanics

> Consider a mass $m$ at position $x(t)$ on a rough horizontal table attached to the origin by a spring with constant $k$ (restoring force $-kx$) and with a dry friction force $f$ 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> f=F, & \text{if $\dot x \lt 0$}\\
> -F \le f \le F, & \text{if $\dot x =0$}\\
> f=-F,& \text{if $\dot x \gt 0$}
> \end{cases}
>  $$
>   a). What is the range of $x$ where the mass can rest?
>
> b) Show that if the mass moves, the maximum excursion decreases by $\frac{2F}{k}$ per half cycle.
>
> c) Discuss the motion

I nearly completed the question, but feel hard to answer part b due to no initial conditions given.

For part b, I started by noting
$$m\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=f-kx$$
Letting $y = \frac{f}{k}-x$, I get
$$m{d^2y \over dt^2}=-ky$$
thus $y = A\cos (\omega t+\phi)$ where $A$ and $\phi$ depend on initial conditions and $\omega= \sqrt \frac{k}{m}$, hence I deduce
$$x= \frac{f}{k}+A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$

If I assume $x(0) \gt 0$, then
$$x= \frac{F}{k}+A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
and hence $$x_{\text{max}_1}= \frac{F}{k}+A$$

In the other half cycle, $\dot x \gt 0$ so
$$x= -\frac{F}{k}+A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
and
$$x_{\text{max}_2}= {-F \over k}+A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
the difference between the previous $x_{\text{max}_1}$ and this $x_{\text{max}_2}$ is $\frac{2F}{k}$.   $\square$

From the previous calculation I feel I have roughly completed the question, but I failed to demonstrate that between $x_{\text{max}_1}$ and $x_{\text{max}_2}$ the mass have moved a half cycle, although intuitively I feel that since it initially move backward($\dot x \lt 0$), when it starts to move forward ($\dot x \gt 0$) and achieve maximum displacement again, it should have completed half cycle.

Could someone help me to make the situation clear please?

Comment: $f(t)$ is not constant, so the transition from $m{d^2x \over dt^2}=f-kx$ to $m{d^2y \over dt^2}=-ky$ is not justified.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "excursion" and "half-cycle"

Comment: I suppose excursion means displacement, and maximum excursion means amplitude. Half-cycle means from one extreme displacement to another extreme displacement (you need to show that the two extreme displacements are consecutive one, not separated by several other extreme displacements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using energy might be easier. I will assume that in part b. the block is released from rest. Let's say it starts a distance $A$ from its equilibrium point and it moves past the equilibrium point a distance $B$ before turning around.

The initial spring energy is equal to the final spring energy plus the energy lost due to the work by friction:

$\frac12 kA^2 = \frac12 kB^2 + FA + FB $

$0 = \frac12 kB^2 + FA + FB -\frac12 kA^2$

Then apply the quadratic formula to get $B$ in terms of $A$. One root is

$B = A -2F/k$

The other root is $B= -A$. I'm not sure of the physical significance of this second root.

Comment: the other root $B = -A$ means the start and end position is the same. i.e. the mass doesn't move at all!

Comment: I need an argument for the reduction of amplitude. More specifically I want to show that it is after **half cycle** that the amplitude has reduced by $2F / k$.

Comment: The amplitude is the magnitude of the displacement from equilibrium to the turning point (where the velocity is momentarily zero). Pick any moment when the block is at a turning point and label its position at that moment $A$. When it has swung its maximum displacement on the other side, that is half a cycle. Label that position $B$. We see that $B$ is less than $A$ by $2F/k$. This means that with each half cycle, the amplitude is reduced by $2F/k$. I can label a new turning point $C$, half a cycle after $B$. I can relate $C$ to $B$ by energy and get $C =B- 2F/k$.

Comment: I just saw this answer. How to prove that the mass is undergoing periodic, though not strictly simple harmonic, motion so the notion of **cycle** is valid?